# Ошибка E0137 выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением C++

Tags: c++

Возникает ошибка в двух последних строках: Ошибка E0137 выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением.

```
void resize() {
    int newM = M * 2;
    LinkedList* newBucketsArray = new LinkedList[newM];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        LinkedList& list = bucketsArray[i];
        HashNode* current = list.head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            HashNode* next = current->next;
            int newIndex = current->key % newM;
            LinkedList& newList = newBucketsArray[newIndex];
            current->next = newList.head;
            newList.head = current;
            current = next;
        }
    }

    delete[] bucketsArray;
    bucketsArray = newBucketsArray; // Ошибка
    M = newM; // Ошибка
}
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Переделанный resize():

```
void resize() {
    int newM = M * 2;
    LinkedList* newBucketsArray = new LinkedList[newM];

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        LinkedList& list = bucketsArray[i];
        HashNode* current = list.head;
        while (current != nullptr) {
            HashNode* next = current->next;
            int newIndex = current->key % newM;
            LinkedList& newList = newBucketsArray[newIndex];
            current->next = newList.head;
            newList.head = current;
            current = next;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        bucketsArray[i].head = nullptr;
    }

    delete[] bucketsArray;
    bucketsArray = newBucketsArray; // Ошибка
}
```

Comment: Какой тип у `bucketsArray` и у `M`?

Comment: const int M = 10000;
LinkedList bucketsArray[M];

Comment: Т.е. вы пытаетесь изменить константу `M`

Comment: Согласен, не логично. Я переделал resize() и попробовал копировать элементы из bucketsArray в newBucketsArray с помощью цикла вместо назначения всего массива, но это все равно не помогло, возникает та же самая ошибка.

Comment: Дайте *минимальный воспроизводимый пример*. Я не Ванга

Comment: @megorit я добавил код к вопросу в конце

Comment: Вы пытетесь присвоить указатель массиву

Comment: Массив, хоть и может неявно приводится к указателю на первый элемент, не является допустимым левосторонним выражением. Формально как-то так. А неформально, так делать нельзя никогда.

Comment: А как тогда это можно исправить?

Comment: Указательи использовать, либо массивы. Вы можете присвоить указатель на первый элемент другому указателю, н оне можете присвоить массиву указатель. Вы понимаете это? Если нет, углубитесь в изучение массивов и указателей. Это бызовые знания без которых никуда.